# How to delete id from one table and id from another table if they are connected to one object?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have these two tables:

Table: REASON

```
id | name
---|------------
1  | gold_sell
2  | gold_buy
4  | Silver_sell
```

Table: REASON_TO_TRANSACTION

```
reason_id | transaction_type
----------|-------------------
1         | sell
2         | buy
4         | pko
```

where `id` from table `reason` is linked with `reason_id` from `reason_to_transaction`.

I want to delete all rows with `id` = 1 from these two tables.

Can someone help me?

I'm using SQL Server(phpmyadmin).

Variable `name` is for getting the current `activeItem` and delete it.

I have written following SQL command:

```
DELETE rt 
  FROM reason_to_transaction rt 
  INNER JOIN reasons r 
    ON id=reason_id 
  WHERE reasons.id=reason_to_transaction.reason_id 
    AND name = 'gold_sell'
```

I also have this angular code:

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(){
        console.log($scope.activeItem);
        var objectToSave = {        
            name: $scope.activeItem.name,
            id: $scope.activeItem.id
        };

        if($scope.activeItem.id){


                defaultAdapter.query('DELETE rt FROM reason_to_transaction rt INNER JOIN reasons r ON r.id = tr.reason_id WHERE name = :name',
              { replacements: objectToSave, type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE }
            ).then(projects => {
              console.log(projects);
              $scope.editMode = false;
                $scope.activeItem = false;
                $scope.refresh();
            });
        } else {         
                defaultAdapter.query('DELETE rt FROM reason_to_transaction rt INNER JOIN reasons r ON r.id = tr.reason_id WHERE name = :name',

              { replacements: objectToSave, type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE }
            ).then(projects => {
              console.log(projects);
              $scope.editMode = false;
                $scope.activeItem = false;
                $scope.refresh();
            });

        }
    };
```

And also have html submit form:

```
<div class="editMode1" style="display: none;">
<div class="form">
<form ng-submit="saveItem(reasonsForm.$valid)" name="reasonsForm">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="currency_code">Име на основание</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="activeItem.name" placeholder="Име на основание за редактиране" />
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="reasonsForm.$invalid" type="submit">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="deleteItem()">Delete</button> <!--ng-click="createUser()"-->

    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="cnlbtn" type="button">Cancel</button>


</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PranavCBalan this not work for me

Comment: what is `rt` is there any meaning of it ?

Comment: @ali_codex it's a table alias

Comment: I'm using MySQL server(I'm coding on Angular with sequelize method for db). And using PhpMyAdmin

Comment: Sorry, but your question has nothing todo with angular ! Your problem is only linked to SQL ! So, if you agree with me, can you please adapt your question in removing 'Angular' and in adding that you are working with SQL Server ? Can you also specify which version ? Can you also correct your SQL command in removing second WHERE and in explaining what you want to do with :name variable ? This is not explain in your question ! Can you make all these changes directly in your question and not in comment so new reader are directly well informed. Thanks.

Comment: @schlebe I make the changes.

Comment: thanks. I have improved the formatting of your question. Can you now explain how much row you want to delete ? 1 row in REASON table ? 1 row in REASON table AND 1 row in TRANSACTION table ? For me your question is not clear. I think that your problem is not linked to DELETE function but simply to SQL. Have you already written a SELECT command that list all rows that you want to delete ?

Comment: I have submit button who call function deleteItem(). This that i want to delete is object from column "name"(from reason table). But this column name is connected with transaction table(with reason_id). 
In short:
I want to delete the name of the reason and delete it accordingly "reason_to_transaction"(reason_id) and the name that corresponds to that name. I want to delete one row from reason and one(or 2,3,4 as they respond to this reason) row from transaction table !